# Why isn't my coding reading the \n

Tags: c

I was writing a code that takes a sentence and reverses it, as an exercise. Here's what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a, sentence[100], sign;
    char *c = sentence; 

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");

    while ( (a = getchar()) != '\n' ) 
    {
        if ( a == '?' || a == '!' || a == '.')
        {
            sign = a;
            break;
        }

        *c = a;
        c++;
    }

    for (char *d = c; d >= sentence; d--)
    {
        if ( (d == sentence) && (*d != ' ') )
        {
            for (char *a = d; a < d + 99; a++)
            {
                if ( (*a == ' ') || (*a == '\n')) //code isn't reading the \n
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                    printf("%c", *a);
            }
        }

        if ( (*d == ' ') && (d != c) && (d != sentence + 99) )  
        {
            for (char *a = d+1; a <=  c; a++)
            {
                if ( (*a == ' ') || (a == c))
                {
                    printf(" ");
                    break;
                }
                else
                    printf("%c", *a);

            }
        }       
    }
    printf("%c\n", sign);

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine when I input a sentence with spaces in it:

> Enter a sentence: This is a sentence
>      sentence a is This

However if I input a string with no spaces, like this:

> Enter a sentence: Thisisasentence

I get an output with what was originally entered ('Thisisasentence'), followed by a lot of gibberish output. From what I understand, this is because the code doesn't go into the `if ( (*a == ' ') || (*a == '\n')` condition.

- Why isn't the compiler reading the '\n'

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char` for good reasons! Read the documenation of functions you use and get the interface right.

Comment: Aside: in `for (char *d = c; d >= sentence; d--)` setting a pointer outside the range of the object, except for one element beyond, is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: ...moreover in the inner loop `for (char *a = d; a < d + 99; a++)` you are dereferencing `*a` which is beyond the data that was written, and the loop limit is likely to break `sentence[100]`.

Comment: It is time to deploy the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program works with a couple of changes.
In the while add `*c = '\0';` after `c++;` to terminate the string.
Check for `a == '\0'` instead of `'\n'` as the while excludes the `'\n'`.
Added a check at the end of the while to make sure no more than 99 characters are allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a, sentence[100], sign;
    char *c = sentence;

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");

    while ( (a = getchar()) != '\n' )
    {
        if ( a == '?' || a == '!' || a == '.')
        {
            sign = a;
            break;
        }

        *c = a;
        c++;
        *c = '\0';//terminate
        if ( c - sentence >= 99) {//make sure not too many characters
            break;
        }
    }

    for (char *d = c; d >= sentence; d--)//start at c and work back to sentence[0]
    {
        if ( (d == sentence) && (*d != ' ') )
        {
            for (char *a = d; !( *a == ' ' || *a == '\0'); a++)
            {
                printf("%c", *a);
            }
        }

        if ( (*d == ' ') && (d != c) && (d != sentence + 99) )
        {
            for (char *a = d+1; a <=  c; a++)
            {
                if ( (*a == ' ') || (a == c))
                {
                    printf(" ");
                    break;
                }
                else
                    printf("%c", *a);

            }
        }
    }
    printf("%c\n", sign);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to split to work into two functions, one for reading a line of text and one for reversing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse_string(char *str) {
    /* skip null */
    if (str == 0) {
        return;
    }

    /* skip empty string */
    if (*str == 0) {
        return;
    }

    /* get range */
    char *start = str;
    char *end = start + strlen(str) - 1; /* -1 for \0 */
    char temp;

    /* reverse */
    while (end > start) {
        /* swap */
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;

        /* move */
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
}

char *read(void) {
    char *line = malloc(100), *linep = line;
    size_t lenmax = 100, len = lenmax;
    int c;

    if (line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (;;) {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;

        if (--len == 0) {
            len = lenmax;
            char *linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);

            if (linen == NULL) {
                free(linep);
                return NULL;
            }
            line = linen + (line - linep);
            linep = linen;
        }

        if ((*line++ = c) == '\n')
            break;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    return linep;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter a sentence:");
    char *sentence = read();
    reverse_string(sentence);
    printf(sentence);
    return 0;
}
```

Test 1

```
Enter a sentence:this is a sentence

ecnetnes a si siht
```

Test 2

```
Enter a sentence:thisisasentence

ecnetnesasisiht
```